# Implementing “Check” in a Chess Game

Tags: java

Hello I am new in Java and I have stuck. I am trying to make chess game, I made everything except check and checkmate method, and if you have any suggestions I will be happy to read them. Here is my work till now:

This is the board class where we play the game:

```
public class Board {

    public static final int COLOR_WHITE = 1;
    public static final int COLOR_BLACK = 2;

    public static PlayingPiece[][] board;
    private boolean isFirstMove;
    private int color;

    public Board() {
        this.setBoard(new PlayingPiece[8][8]);
        this.isFirstMove = true;
        this.initializePieces();

    }

    // Initialize the chess pieces
    public void initializePieces() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            board[1][i] = new Pawn(1, i, COLOR_WHITE);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            board[6][i] = new Pawn(6, i, COLOR_BLACK);
        }

        board[0][0] = new Rook(0, 0, COLOR_WHITE);
        board[0][7] = new Rook(0, 7, COLOR_WHITE);
        board[7][0] = new Rook(7, 0, COLOR_BLACK);
        board[7][7] = new Rook(7, 7, COLOR_BLACK);

        board[0][1] = new Knight(0, 1, COLOR_WHITE);
        board[0][6] = new Knight(0, 6, COLOR_WHITE);
        board[7][1] = new Knight(7, 1, COLOR_BLACK);
        board[7][6] = new Knight(7, 6, COLOR_BLACK);

        board[0][2] = new Officer(0, 2, COLOR_WHITE);
        board[0][5] = new Officer(0, 5, COLOR_WHITE);
        board[7][2] = new Officer(7, 2, COLOR_BLACK);
        board[7][5] = new Officer(7, 5, COLOR_BLACK);

        board[0][3] = new Queen(3, 0, COLOR_WHITE);
        board[0][4] = new King(4, 0, COLOR_WHITE);
        board[7][3] = new Queen(7, 3, COLOR_BLACK);
        board[7][4] = new King(7, 4, COLOR_BLACK);

        this.printBoard();

    }

    public boolean play(int color, int fromX, int fromY, int toX, int toY) {


        boolean isTrue = false;
        // Check if this is the first turn and only white can move
        if (isFirstMove && color == COLOR_WHITE) {
            isTrue = true;

        } else if (isFirstMove && color == COLOR_BLACK) {
            return false;
        }
        // check if player plays 2 times in a raw and if you move the piece from
        // current possition
        if (color == this.color || (toX == fromX && toY == fromY)) {
            return false;
        }

        isTrue = true;

        if (isTrue == true) {

            this.isFirstMove = false;
            // Check if player plays with his own color
            if (((board[fromX][fromY]).getColor() != color)) {
                return false;
            }


            // Check the isLegal movement of every chess piece
            if ((board[fromX][fromY]).move(toX, toY)) {
                board[toX][toY] = board[fromX][fromY];
                board[fromX][fromY] = null;
            }

            this.printBoard();

        }
        return isTrue;
    }

    public PlayingPiece[][] getBoard() {
        return board;
    }

    public void setBoard(PlayingPiece[][] board) {
        Board.board = board;
    }
```

This is the Pieces class with all kind of pieces:

```
    package com.chess.www;
public class PlayingPiece {

    public static final int COLOR_WHITE = 1;
    public static final int COLOR_BLACK = 2;
    public static final char BLACK_PAWN = '\u265F';
    public static final char BLACK_ROOK = '\u265C';
    public static final char BLACK_KNIGHT = '\u265E';
    public static final char BLACK_BISHOP = '\u265D';
    public static final char BLACK_QUEEN = '\u265B';
    public static final char BLACK_KING = '\u265A';
    public static final char WHITE_PAWN = '\u2659';
    public static final char WHITE_ROOK = '\u2656';
    public static final char WHITE_KNIGHT = '\u2658';
    public static final char WHITE_BISHOP = '\u2657';
    public static final char WHITE_QUEEN = '\u2655';
    public static final char WHITE_KING = '\u2654';
    public static final char NO_PIECE = ' ';

    private int x, y;
    private boolean isAlive;
    private int color;
    private char symbol;


    protected PlayingPiece (int newX, int newY, int newColor) {
        this.setX(newX);
        this.setY(newY);
        this.color = newColor;
        this.isAlive = true;

    }

    protected PlayingPiece(int newX, int newY) {
        this.setX(newX);
        this.setY(newY);
    }


    protected PlayingPiece() {

    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }
    public void setY(int y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    protected boolean moveIsLegal (int newX, int newY) {
        boolean isLegal = false;

        if ((0 <= newX && newX <= 7) && (0 <= newY && newY <= 7)){

            isLegal = true;
        }
        return isLegal;
    }

    public boolean move (int newX, int newY) {
        if (moveIsLegal(newX, newY)) {
            setX(newX);
            setY(newY);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public int getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public boolean isAlive() {
        return isAlive;
    }

    public void setAlive(boolean isAlive) {
        this.isAlive = isAlive;
    }

    public char getSymbol() {
        return symbol;
    }

    public void setSymbol(char symbol) {
        this.symbol = symbol;
    }



}
```

And here is the King class:

```
package com.chess.www;

public class King extends PlayingPiece {

    public King(int newX, int newY, int color) {
        super(newX, newY, color);

        if (color == COLOR_BLACK) {
            this.setSymbol(BLACK_KING);
        } else {
            this.setSymbol(WHITE_KING);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected boolean moveIsLegal(int newX, int newY) {

        int newPositionX = newX - getX();
        int newPositionY = newY - getY();
        int checkX = this.getX();
        int checkY = this.getY();

        if (super.moveIsLegal(newX, newY)) {

            if ((Math.abs(newPositionX) == 1) && (newY == getY())) {

                while (checkX != newX) {

                    if (this.isValidTraceX(checkX, newY, newX)) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (checkX > newX) {
                        checkX--;
                    } else if (this.getX() < newX) {
                        checkX++;
                    }

                }

            } else if ((newX == getX()) && (Math.abs(newPositionY) == 1)) {

                while (checkY != newY) {

                    if (this.isValidTraceY(newX, checkY, newY)) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (checkY > newY) {
                        checkY--;
                    } else if (this.getY() < newY) {
                        checkY++;
                    }

                }

            } else if ((Math.abs(newPositionY) == 1) == (Math.abs(newPositionX) == 1)) {

                while (checkX != newX && checkY != newY) {

                    if (this.isValidTrace(checkX, checkY, newX, newY)) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    if (checkX > newX) {
                        checkX--;
                    } else if (this.getX() < newX) {
                        checkX++;
                    }

                    if (checkY > newY) {
                        checkY--;
                    } else if (this.getY() < newY) {
                        checkY++;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        return false;
    }

    public boolean isValidTraceX(int newX, int newY, int lastX) {

        boolean isValid = true;
        if ((Board.board[newX][newY]) != null) {
            isValid = false;
        }
        if (((Board.board[lastX][newY]) != null)) {
            if (Board.board[lastX][newY].getColor() == this.getColor()) {
                isValid = false;
            } else {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }

        return isValid;

    }

    public boolean isValidTraceY(int newX, int newY, int lastY) {

        boolean isValid = true;
        if ((Board.board[newX][newY]) != null) {
            isValid = false;
        }
        if (((Board.board[newX][lastY]) != null)) {
            if (Board.board[newX][lastY].getColor() == this.getColor()) {
                isValid = false;
            } else {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }

        return isValid;

    }

    public boolean isValidTrace(int newX, int newY, int lastX, int lastY) {

        boolean isValid = true;
        if ((Board.board[newX][newY]) != null) {
            isValid = false;
        }
        if (((Board.board[lastX][lastY]) != null)) {
            if (Board.board[lastX][lastY].getColor() == this.getColor()) {
                isValid = false;
            } else {
                isValid = true;
            }
        }

        return isValid;

    }
}
```

I want to implement the method for check in board class do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I'd suggest a boolean `check(PlayingPiece)` method you can call after each move. There you should have the current position of that piece and look for the position of the opponent's king. If the piece is allowed to use that position (`isLegal()`?) -> check = true;

Answer (score 0):

The way I would implement would be just a method in the King class called something like, isChecked.

```
boolean isChecked() {
    /* Check straight lines */
    for (directions) { // up, down, left and right
        for (square in direction) { // square by square from the king and out in the current direction
            if (square contains opponent rook or queen)
                return true;
            else if (square contains friendly piece)
                continue;

    /* Check diagonals */
    for (directions) { // left-up, left-down, right-up and right-down
        for (square in direction) { // square by square from the king and out in the current direction
            if (square contains opponent bishop or queen)
                return true;
            else if (square contains friendly piece)
                continue;

    /* Check pawns */
    if (squares where pawns would threaten the king contains pawns)
        return true;

    /* Check king, this is to find if a square is legal to move to only */
    if (squares where a king would threaten the king contains king)
        return true;

    /* Check knights */
    if (squares where knights would threaten the king contains knights)
        return true;
```

Sorry, I haven't really got time to write the entire code now, but the pseudo code should be enough to understand the concept. If you need I could fix it later today.

The principle is just, check every possible way a king can be checked.
If a king is checked and all possible moves are also checked, it is a checkmate.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
    public class KingsChecker {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

            int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
            String[][] chess = new String[n][n];
            print(chess,n);

}
 public static void print (String[][] chess,int n) {

        for(int i = 0; i< chess.length; i++) {

            double random = Math.random()*n; //to generate a random number.

            for(int j = 0; j < chess[i].length; j++) {

                int column = (int)random;   
                int[] count = new int[n];

                chess[i][j]= "+";
                count[column]++;

                if (count[column]<=1){
                    chess[i][column]="k";
                     System.out.print(chess[i][j]);
                 }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
 }
    }
```